# Regex - Empty field in form validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have an existing regex:

```
/^(\d*)(\.(\d*))?$|^$/
```

How do i add/modify a check for empty field - (\s*) to this? - trying to learn regex, did a search but did not find apt resources.

Comment: Your existing regex is already redundant, since the first branch already allows empty input (`*` allows zero, `?` makes the other piece optional)...

Comment: you have a lot of questions and no accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `|^$` part is redundant. But if you're trying to disallow an empty field, you could try this instead:

```
/^\d*\.?\d+$/
```

If you want to ignore whitespace at the beginning and end, try this:

```
/^\s*\d*\.?\d+\s*$/
```

Your wording is a little unclear, so let me know if this isn't what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to validate price field - that should not allow white spaces, alphabets & negative values - and should allow numbers,commas and decimals - none of the solutions here works -

Answer (score 0):

So your regexp says:

> Match from the beginning – ^ – zero or more digit – \d* –, that maybe is followed by a dot and zero or more digit – (.(\d*))? – without anything after – $, end of string. Or – | – match the beginning of the string followed by the end of the string – ^$ –.

What you have to modify it's the last part. Instead of `^$`, you can match `^\s*$`, that is read as *"match the beginning of the string, followed by zero or more whitespaces, and the end of the string"*. So it matches both the previous condition (zero whitespace means from the beginning to the end) and the new condition – with some whitespaces.

Hope that it helps to understand better the regexp. Unfortunately I don't know any good resource for RegExp, I just use the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: /^(\d*)(\.(\d*))?$|^\s*$/ - so this one not validating empty values in the field, also does this regex block the (,) .. it is not allowing comma too

Comment: `/^(\d*)(\.(\d*))?$|^\s*$/.test("   ") === true`, so it matches empty values, where the previous didn't: `/^(\d*)(\.(\d*))?$|^$/.test("   ") === false`. About the comma, I just modified the regexp, explaining step by step, so it behaves like the previous one for commas – it doesn't validate for commas; the previous didn't and the question didn't mentioned them. I just replied to the answer trying to explain how to read the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%28?%3a%28%5Cd%2a%29%28?%3a%5C.%28%5Cd%2a%29%29?%7C%5Cs%2a%29%24&flags=m&str=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%09%09%0A1234.34) to help you with your regex? I think this is the regex you're looking for:

```
^(?:(\d*)(?:\.(\d*))?|\s*)$
```

It will match either a floating point number or some whitespace. Note that the floating point number can be weirdly formatted. For example, `0000.10` would match.